# Using CSS or Java to Show or Hide Empty Content Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a page template that uses section headers and subsequent content that is being dynamically pulled in based on a separate database. Currently I have the page set up to look something like this:

```
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h3>Product Applications</h3>
        {tag_applications}<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Where the Product Applications is a formatted header on the page and the {tag_applications} is link through the CMS that is pulling in content from a field defined elsewhere. I am trying to figure out how to hide the entire cell (or div if I need to) with either CSS or a script when the {tag_applications} is empty or blank. I tried to use the 'empty' tag in CSS on the cell and setting the display to hidden, but of course, the cell is not actually empty because of the header.

What is the best way that I can accomplish this without creating separate pages for each item?

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably use the JQuery show and hide functions.

Comment: It seems actually hiding and showing the sections isn't the problem.  You need an easier way to determine if the table cell contains anything else besides the heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your content area in a div, like this:

```
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h3>Product Applications</h3>
        <div class="contentSection">{tag_applications}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Then your script can check if the div is empty or not. (uses jQuery)

```
$(function()
{
    $(".contentSection").each(function(idx, ele)
    {
        if($(ele).html() == "")
            $(ele).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

My apologies if I made any syntax errors...